# Get base Elastic Beanstalk AMI for arm64 architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a custom AMI for Elastic Beanstalk using the instructions from the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html). However, when I run the `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-platform-version` command for my required platform (Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2), it only gives me the base AMI for the x86_64 architecture, but I want to use arm64.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-platform-version \
  --platform-arn "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2::platform/Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.2.16" \
  --query 'PlatformDescription.CustomAmiList[?starts_with(ImageId, `ami-`)][].ImageId' \
  --output text
```

The only ways I've found to get the arm64 AMI are manual: either via the Elastic Beanstalk console (choose arm64... it shows the AMI there), or more of a manual search on the EC2 launch instance page.

Is there a simple CLI command that will give me the base EB AMI for arm64?

Answer (score 0):

I opened an AWS support case looking for an automated way to get the AMI ID, and this was their response:

> I have replicated and tested. Unfortunately, there is no feasible workaround for it.
>
> I have reached out to the service team and created the feature request to add/update via CLI command to return arm ami-id, however there is no ETA.  Since we do not have visibility into the internal team's workflow, we cannot provide an ETA on the same.